# PhpStorm9 проблема с путями

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, пути

Есть строка
`<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/header.php");?>`
при дебаге всплывает ошибка

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/bitrix/header.php' (include_path='.;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.4;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.4/PEAR/pear') in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\index.php on line 2
```

Если в файле прописать абсолютный путь, то заработает до следующего require. В шторме ставил Mark as Resource root, не помогло.

Как заставить шторм определить папку localhost как корень?